# can't solve "string too long" failure when importing csv to sql using python

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, string, pyodbc

When I try to import data to sql using python I keep getting string too long exception on a string that is 285 characters long.

I have defined the TweetText-column type in GG as varchar(max) and when I paste the string manually, instead of TweetText.row, and try to import it using this code it works fine which is why i think it is row.TweetText that creates the mistake. Do you have an idea as to why it says string too long?

The code:

```
import sys
import pypyodbc as odbc
import pandas as pd
import os
import csv
def connect(path):
    data = pd.read_csv (path)
    data.rename( columns={'Unnamed: 0':'TweetNumber'}, inplace=True )
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    SERVER_NAME = 'DESKTOP-9736NS2\SQLEXPRESS'
    DATABASE_NAME = 'DB.Tweets'
    DRIVER= 'SQL Server'
    conn_string = f"""
        Driver={{{DRIVER}}};
        Server={{{SERVER_NAME}}};
        Database={{{DATABASE_NAME}}};
        Trust_Connection=yes;
    """
    try:
        conn = odbc.connect(conn_string)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print('task is terminated')
        sys.exit()
    else:
        cursor = conn.cursor()

    insert_statement = """
        INSERT INTO [GG]
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
    """
    try: 
        toggle =0
        for row in df.itertuples():
            cursor.execute(insert_statement,(row.TweetNumber, row.UserName, row.RealName, row.FollowerCount, row.TweetCount, row.TweetText, row.TweetLikes, row.TweetRetweets, row.TweetId, row.DatePosted, row.MediaUrl))
            if toggle ==0:
                print(print(row.UserName))
                toggle=1
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        cursor.rollback()
        print('transaction rolled back')
        stop=1
    else:
        print('records inserted succesfully')
        cursor.commit()
        cursor.close()
        stop=0
    finally:
        if conn.connected == 1:
            print('connection closed')
            conn.close()
    return(stop)
    
g=1
stop = 0
for filename in os.scandir('C:/Users/Christian/OneDrive - University of Copenhagen/Documents/UniKU/AProjects/DatabaseProject/TwitterTweetData'):
    if stop ==0:
        if g == 1:
            if filename.is_file():
                connect(filename.path)
                stop=connect(filename.path)
```

The SQL datatypes:

[Datatypes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSD2m.png)

Comment: What is the *actual* error you are getting? "String too long" isn't an error/exception in SQL Server, so this suggest the problem is in your python, not the SQL.

Comment: `INSERT INTO [GG] VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)` is a code smell, too. Despite the column list being optional in an insert statement you should always include it to protect against issues such as column reordering. i.e.: `INSERT INTO Schema.Table (Column1, Column2, ..., ColumnN) VALUES (Value1, Value2, ..., Value2)`.